# vhdl bitwise operation on vector

Tags: function, vector, vhdl, bitwise-operators

trying to mimic the verilog behavior regarding the bitwise operations (meaning - an operation that works on all bits of a vector and output 1 bit answer.

example:

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
...
signal vect  : std_logic_vector (length -1 downto 0);
signal ans   : std_logic;
signal addin : std_logic;
```

when vect = all '0' i will want ans to be '1' (nor)

when vect = all '1' i will want ans to be '1' (and)

when vect = even num of '1' i will want ans to be '1' (xor)
, etc.

i made the following functions (only one is shown here):

```
function vand (vect :std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
  variable temp : std_logic;
begin 
  temp := '1';
  for I in (vect'length -1) downto 0 loop
    temp := temp and vect(I);
  end loop;
  return temp;
end;
```

this function should give the "AND" on all bits.
so, here comes my questions:

a. is there an easier way to make such operations?

b. i'm using Vand like this `if Vand(vect & addin) = '1' do something...` but when vect is '0H' and addin is 'H' the condition is filled and I have no idea why. can someone think why this kind of operation is problematic? the function behaves itself on other cases, but here i tested it for rapid change immunity and got this unwanted behavir.

## edit

i do not know the length of the vector 'vect' or the vector 'vect & addin'.

## edit 2

solved the second problem by creating a sub function `Vand(vect : std_logic_vector; b: std_logic)` that uses the original `Vand` (and found a bug in my Vnor along the way). still hoping for a better solution than these two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions called `or_reduce` and `and_reduce` which do what you want.  They also call `to_X01` on the inputs, which means that `H` and `L`s will be converted to `1` and `0`.

They can be found in `std_logic_misc` for `std_logic_vector`s and are proposed for the next rev of VHDL for `ieee.numeric_std` for `signed` and `unsigned` vectors.

VHDL-2008 also allows this syntax on `std_logic_vector`s:

```
anded <= and v;
ored <= or v;
```

Comment: Tried to find e.g. `or_reduce` in my local numeric_std, but could only find anything in Synopsys std_logic_misc; any suggestion for where to look ?

Comment: @MortenZdk - I couldn't find any reduction logical operators in http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/ or http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/ (IEEE-SA Supplemental Material).  I did find them in ghdl's Synopsys libraries, specifically std_logic_misc.  They can also be found in David Bishops proposed math extensions (http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/), http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/numeric_std_additions.vhdl, http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/numeric_std_additions.html (User Guide). Proposed for VHDL-201X.

Comment: @Koontz: Thanks for the feedback, and the IEEE links :-)

Comment: @David Koontz: thanks for the location, indeed it was in the std_logic_misc package. funny, when i opened the package and loocked at the functions, they are exactly as i implemented them :)

Comment: Martin Thompson: Thanks for the answer